# Error while using BatchGraph with TitanGraph

Tags: database, cassandra, batch-processing, graph-databases, titan

I am trying to load the data in Titan using BatchGraph. With TitanGraph as a object parameter.

According to [Batch Implementation](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Batch-Implementation) by Tinkerpop, This is how implementation should be:

```
TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("titan-cassandra.properties");
BatchGraph bgraph = new BatchGraph( g, VertexIDType.STRING, 1000);
```

But In BatchGraph constructor requires the TrasanctionalGraph object. So when I cast it as :

```
TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("titan-cassandra.properties");

 BatchGraph bgraph = new BatchGraph( (TransactionalGraph) g, VertexIDType.STRING, 1000)
```

This gives following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.TransactionalGraph
```

How to use BatchGraph in this case? How it can be handled?

I am using Titan 1.0.0 and Blueprints 2.7.0 with cassandra version 2.2.4.

Thanks.

Comment: did you finally recreated the batch graph behaviour using caches, as suggested below?

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `BatchGraph` from Blueprints (TinkerPop 2.x) with Titan 1.0. They are not compatible.  Titan 1.0 supports TinkerPop 3.x and there is no `BatchGraph` in TinkerPop 3.x.

`BatchGraph` is pretty simple to recreate. It basically just hides a cache of newly inserted vertices that tracks their ids for future lookup.  Using this in-memory cache will be faster than Titan's index lookups.  You could use existing caches like [guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) to replicate this.

If your graph is very large, you can load your data with [BLVP](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#_loading_with_bulkloadervertexprogram) (BulkLoaderVertexProgram). There is some demonstration of that [here](https://github.com/dkuppitz/openflights). Note that the link to BLVP above is to the version currently supported by Titan 1.0.0 - the documentation and support has improved for the future 1.1.0 found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#bulkloadervertexprogram). There are also better examples of [BLVP usage with Spark](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#sparkgraphcomputer) and other providers.

Comment: How does the Spark work here, do I have to run the spark explicitly or it is there already in Titan? Do I have to use Hadoop/Spark to bulk load or is there any other way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187601/how-to-load-millions-of-vertices-from-csv-into-titan-1-0-0-using-bulkloaderverte

Answer (score 0):

A quick and naive implementation on recreating the BatchGraph behaviour might be the following (using Google's Guava library for the cache):

```
import com.google.common.cache.*;

// Define schema & indexes...
...

// Cache definition 
// In my case, I can handle all vertices in memory
cacheSize = 2000000;
vertexCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .maximumSize(cacheSize)
  .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  .build();

nUsers = 0
println 'Loading vertices...';
// Load vertices
new File('/tmp/vertices.txt').eachLine {
  try {
    fields = it.split('\t').take(8);
    userId = fields[0];
    isPublic = fields[1] == '1' ? true : false;
    completionPercentage = fields[2]
    gender = fields[3] == '1' ? 'male' : 'female';
    region = fields[4];
    lastLogin = fields[5];
    registration = fields[6];
    age = fields[7] as int;
    v = graph.addVertex('userId', userId, 'isPublic', isPublic, 'completionPercentage', completionPercentage, 'gender', gender, 'region', region, 'lastLogin', lastLogin, 'registration', registration, 'age', age);
    // Add vertex to the cache
    vertexCache.put(userId, v);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Silently skip...
    // e.printStackTrace();
  }
  nUsers += 1
  if (nUsers % 10000 == 0) {
    println String.valueOf(nUsers) + ' vertices loaded so far...';
    graph.tx().commit();
  }
};
println 'Vertices load finished';

// Load relations
nLinks = 0;
println 'Loading links ...';
new File('/tmp/edges.txt').eachLine {
  try {
    fields = it.split('\t');
    from = fields[0];
    to = fields[1];
    fromVertex = vertexCache.getIfPresent(from);
    toVertex = vertexCache.getIfPresent(to);
    if (fromVertex != null && toVertex != null)
      toVertex.addEdge('connectedTo', fromVertex);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Silently skip...
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  nLinks += 1;
  if (nLinks % 10000 == 0) {
    println String.valueOf(nLinks) + ' links loaded so far...';
    graph.tx().commit();
  }
};

graph.close()
```

I tested it with a graph with ~1.7M vertices and ~30M edges (batch loading activated in storage backend, this forces you to define all your schema beforehand but it is actually considered a good practice to do so) and it was successfully loaded in less than 10 minutes. When using storage indexes for vertices retrieval while creating the edges, the load process took more than 1 hour.